# Pulling data from MySQL only if a certain field is not empty

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use a WHERE statement to pull info where  the field `t.twittername` is not empty.  The code below doesn't work.  What kind of WHERE statement can I use?

**EDIT:** I tried `WHERE t.twittername IS NOT NULL` but that still didn't work.

**EDIT:** I am now showing the full SQL statement.

Here is the SQL for the table `tweets`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tweets` (
  `tweetid` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `submissionid` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `shorturl` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `loginid` varchar(11) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `twittername` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tweetid`)
```

Code:

```
 $sqlStr3 = "SELECT
                 l.username 
                 ,l.loginid  
                 ,t.tweetid 
                 ,t.shorturl 
                 ,t.twittername 
                 ,t.time
                 ,s.submissionid 
                 ,s.title
                 ,s.url 
                 ,s.displayurl 
                 ,s.datesubmitted
                 ,s.points
                 ,COUNT(t.tweetid) countTweets 
        FROM tweets AS t        
      WHERE TRIM (t.twittername) IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(t.twittername) != ''
  INNER JOIN login AS l ON t.loginid = l.loginid
  INNER JOIN submission AS s ON t.submissionid = s.submissionid
        GROUP BY t.tweetid  
    ORDER BY t.time DESC
       LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
WHERE t.twittername IS NOT NULL
```

**EDIT - after comment:**

try this "extreme" version for checking a string field for emptiness:

```
WHERE TRIM (t.twittername) IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(t.twittername) != ''
```

EDIT 2 - another point:

Your SQL statement is odd - you refer to `s` but I can't see an `s` and you use `COUNT` but I don't see a `GROUP BY` and I would expect some sort of JOIN too which I don't see... please show the real statement...

**EDIT 3 - after the OP showed the statement and table definition:**

I actually don't understand what this statement should generate BUT give the following a try:

```
SELECT
             l.username 
             ,l.loginid  
             ,t.tweetid 
             ,t.shorturl 
             ,t.twittername 
             ,t.time
             ,s.submissionid 
             ,s.title
             ,s.url 
             ,s.displayurl 
             ,s.datesubmitted
             ,s.points
             ,COUNT(t.tweetid) countTweets 
    FROM tweets AS t        
INNER JOIN login AS l ON t.loginid = l.loginid
INNER JOIN submission AS s ON t.submissionid = s.submissionid
  WHERE TRIM (t.twittername) IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(t.twittername) != ''
    GROUP BY 
             l.username 
             ,l.loginid  
             ,t.tweetid 
             ,t.shorturl 
             ,t.twittername 
             ,t.time
             ,s.submissionid 
             ,s.title
             ,s.url 
             ,s.displayurl 
             ,s.datesubmitted
             ,s.points
ORDER BY t.time DESC
   LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage
```

Comment: see my edit above... if this still does not work then please give the field/table definition

Comment: see my edit above - if this still "doesn't work" you need to put up some example data, result you get and result you want!

Answer (score 1):

You can test if a column is null by using the `is` operator :

```
-- ...
WHERE t.twittername IS NOT NULL;
```

Also, do not confuse the lack of data (NULL) and en empty string (`''`, which **is** a value). If you want to test if the string is empty, do something like this :

```
-- ...
WHERE t.twittername = '';
```